# Prove the following quantity is always nonnegative

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove that $$f(x, y) \equiv \arccos\left(\frac{x-y}{K}\right) - \arccos\left(\frac{x-y}{K}+y\right) - \frac{y}{x}\arccos(1-y^2) \ge 0$$

with the constraints:

1. $K\ge 2$ is an integer,
2. $g(x, y) = (K-1)y^2+x^2-K=0$,
3. $1\le x\le \sqrt{K}$,
4. $0\le y\le 1$.

Furthermore, $f(x, y) = 0$ if and only if $x=y=1$ or $x=\sqrt{K}$ and $y=0$.

Numerically it seems to be correct. Also $K=2$ it can be proven.

Note that the inequality could also be replaced with $$f_2(x, y) = \arccos\left(\frac{x-y}{K}\right) - \arccos\left(\frac{x-y}{K}+y\right) - \frac{y}{x}\arccos(1-y) \ge 0$$ since $f \ge f_2$. So if $f_2 \ge 0$ then $f \ge 0$.

[image: Blue curve is $f$ and orange one is $f_2$.]

Blue curve is $f$ and orange one is $f_2$ when $K=3$. The $x$-axis is $x$, variable $y$ has been replace by $y = \sqrt{\frac{K-x^2}{K-1}}$.

**What I have tried:**

1. Setting $y = \sqrt{\frac{K-x^2}{K-1}}$ and try showing $f''_x(x, y(x)) > 0$. Numerically it is correct but the expression seems to be too complicated to prove.
2. Using $\arccos(a) - \arccos(b) = \int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\mathrm{d}z$ to expand $f$ as the subtraction of two integrals. Then if the integrand is positive then things are proved. It works for most $z$ except for a small vicinity at $z=1$, in which the integrand is negative. Numerical test shows it is indeed the case.
3. Use Lagrange multiplier. $\lambda$ is easy to compute. But the second derivative seems to be too messy..

Comment: Post updated. See above.